# call mysql function or stored procedure with 'out' parameter in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have used mysql stored procedure in php, but i need to return few values from my sql, so i am planning to use mysql functions or stored procedure with ''out'parameter.

it would be good if anyone can help me on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found solution for this

http://blog.ulf-wendel.de/2011/using-mysql-stored-procedures-with-php-mysqli/

```
  $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "test");
if (!$mysqli->query("DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS p") ||
    !$mysqli->query('CREATE PROCEDURE p(OUT msg VARCHAR(50)) BEGIN SELECT "Hi!" INTO msg; END;'))
   echo "Stored procedure creation failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;

if (!$mysqli->query("SET @msg = ''") ||
    !$mysqli->query("CALL p(@msg)"))
 echo "CALL failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;

if (!($res = $mysqli->query("SELECT @msg as _p_out")))
 echo "Fetch failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;

$row = $res->fetch_assoc();
echo $row['_p_out'];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PHP `PDO` extension, try this code below

```
<?php
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("CALL sp_returns_string(?)");
    // assumes that the output is VARCHAR(100) 
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $return_value, PDO::PARAM_STR, 100); 
    // call the stored procedure
    $stmt->execute();

    print "procedure returned $return_value\n";
?>
```

`Output parameters` are slightly more complex to use than input parameters, in that a *developer must know how large a given parameter* might be when they bind it. *If the value turns out to be larger* than the size they suggested, an *error is raised*.